# Compare and Represent Data With Different Number of Elements

Tags: data-analysis

I have N entities that I want to compare them to; for example, A has 5 options, B has 3 options, and C has 6 options.  1 means an option exists, 0 otherwise as in the example next:

A = [1 1 0 1 1] (satisfied by 4 options out of 5)

B = [1 0 0] (satisfied with 1 option out of 3)

C = [0 0 0 0 0 1] (satisfied with 1 option out of 6)

If we want to plot this data to show their performance, we can see that the max of each entity is not the same,  so the y-axis might not represent the actual data.. how can we handle this issue?

We can't pad because they are different entities; padding would mean it is absent, which is incorrect.

I don't want also to plot them with a relative axis or stacked bar-plot.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What sort of comparison do you have in mind?  How would you "compare" the three examples you provided?

Comment: The one that satisfies more options would be said to be more efficient than the others. Here, it is A.  I can't see how to visualize this result.

Comment: So just rank them by the number of $1's$.  Or do you have a way to compare $[1,1]$ and $[1,1,0,0,0,0,0]$ for example.

Comment: Grouping them like this will not be the solution I need. It has to be individual. I was thinking now, since the result is either 1s or 0s, can we use some kind of normalization?

Comment: This is too vague.  How are you comparing them?  If it's more than just the number of $1's$, what else are you considering?    There isn't any universal way to compare these things, it all comes down to what you had in mind.

Comment: I suggest:  edit your post to supply more examples of the sort of comparisons you have in mind.  How, say, would you compare $[1,0]$ and $[0,1]$?  What about $[1]$ versus $[1,0]$?  What other comparisons can you illustrate that might reveal the underlying data structure you have in mind?

Comment: You are right, it is what I have in mind, I will use the number of 1s and 0s method (that is what I have in mind) in the previous comments. Thanks, I appreciate the time.